# Telerik controls for Asp.net: Radgrid checkbox column not working properly with scrolling

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, telerik, scroll, radgrid

I'm having trouble scrolling my RadGrid which contains a CheckBox column. The problem is that the CheckBoxes don't scroll with the other columns grid, and the position of the CheckBoxes become static.

Here is my code in html:

```
<Rad:RadGrid ID="grid1" Width="800px" Height="415px" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="false" AllowMultiRowSelection="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnNeedDataSource="CustomFormTemplatesGrid_NeedDataSource" >
    <MasterTableView Width="800px" TableLayout="Fixed" EnableHeaderContextMenu="true">
        <HeaderStyle Wrap="true" />
        <Columns>
            <Rad:GridBoundColumn DataField="FormName" UniqueName="FormName" HeaderText="Form Name" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" DataFormatString="<nobr>{0}&nbsp;</nobr>"/>
            <Rad:GridBoundColumn DataField="FormDisplayName" UniqueName="FormDisplayName" HeaderText="Form Display Name" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" DataFormatString="<nobr>{0}&nbsp;</nobr>" />
            <Rad:GridBoundColumn DataField="Version" UniqueName="Version" HeaderText="Version" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" DataFormatString="<nobr>{0}&nbsp;</nobr>"  />
            <Rad:GridBoundColumn DataField="ModuleName" UniqueName="ModuleName" HeaderText="Selected Module Name" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" DataFormatString="<nobr>{0}&nbsp;</nobr>" />
            <Rad:GridBoundColumn DataField="CreatedDateTime" UniqueName="CreatedDateTime" HeaderText="Created Date/Time" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" CurrentFilterFunction="NoFilter" DataFormatString="<nobr>{0}&nbsp;</nobr>"  />
            <Rad:GridBoundColumn DataField="CreatedBy" UniqueName="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Created By" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true" DataFormatString="<nobr>{0}&nbsp;</nobr>" />
            <Rad:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="Deleted" UniqueName="Deleted" HeaderText="Deleted" />
        </Columns>
        <SortExpressions>
            <Rad:GridSortExpression FieldName="FormName" SortOrder="Ascending" ></Rad:GridSortExpression>
        </SortExpressions>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="False" EnableRowHoverStyle="false">
        <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" EnableRealTimeResize="false" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="false" AllowResizeToFit="true" ></Resizing>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="False"></Scrolling>
        <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="gridCustomFormTemplates_RowSelected" />                       
    </ClientSettings>
</Rad:RadGrid>
```

I am loading the grid datasource on code behind and binding properly.
Data is displayed but the problem with CheckBoxes remains as mentioned above.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem long ago. Probably this problem is caused by a bug in IE. To resolve this issue

```
.RadGrid .rgDataDiv
{
    position: relative;
}
```

Hope this helps :) .